# HTML form label style in CSS not applied to label tags in html

Tags: html, css, forms

I've seen a variant of my issue asked more than a few times but all the takeaways from those instances have not worked for me.  In short, what is wrong with my HTML or CSS that the label styling is not working?

```css
    label {
     font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: #ff0000;
    }
```

```html
    <form action="index.php" method="post">

    <h2>Add New Location</h2><br>

    <label for="name">Location: </label>
    <input type="text" size="75" name="name"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Add">
    <input type="hidden" name="content" value="add_new_location">

    </form>
```

It has to be something obvious but after 3 hours I surrender.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong since it's perfectly working. https://jsfiddle.net/bryanaldrin/0q4z85xt/1/

Comment: Looks perfect??

Comment: Have you tried using the developer tools in your browser to see which style the label uses?

Comment: If the code in your example is not working for you, then you are probably not loading the CSS correctly.  How are you loading the CSS? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/site.css">`?  Is the CSS file served with the correct MIME type (`text/css`)?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input.  As suggested I'll take a look at the developer tools in the browser.  Thanks for suggesting the possibility Lee but the CSS is being loaded properly as the other styles in the file are working as desired.  It's just the label that's the problem.  Also, if it helps, when I remove the <label> tag and use <h3> and change the CSS accordingly the font-size property is applied but font-family and color are not.  So. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not loading the CSS. The code is perfectly fine. Maybe it is the problem with the program running the code? I am perfectly getting this result. I believe the exact problem is that you did not identify the link to the style sheet. You can do this through the usage of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/site.css">`(credit to @LeeKowalkowski) Another, possible easy option is to use the `<style></style>` tags and put your css inside of it. In your case, it would be:

```
<style>
    label {
        font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ff0000;
    }
</style>
 <form action="index.php" method="post">

    <h2>Add New Location</h2><br>

<label for="name">Location: </label>
<input type="text" size="75" name="name"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Add">
<input type="hidden" name="content" value="add_new_location">

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Azync for the input.  The CSS is being loaded via another php file.  The form gets passed to that file via include().  I did figure out the issue a few minutes ago--the <h2> tag nested within the <form> tag was causing the problem.  I moved <h2> out and it now works.  Thanks again for chiming in.

Comment: @Jason Try getting rid of the br tag. I don't think that the h2 tag is supposed to be the problem.